# Получить рандомное чило с коэфицентом

Tags: php

Как можно реализовать рандом с процентом выпадения?

К примеру есть 4 числа(может быть и больше), 10, 15, 40, 12 но у 10 процент выпадения 20%, у 15 = 25%, у 40 = 5%, а у 12 = 50%, возможно есть какая-то библиотека?

Comment: Да MatLab но проще самому такое реализовать. Почитайте про виды распределений и как их генерировать. Но в общем случае когда точность не так важна (когда Вы не физик ядерщик) достаточно самому написать функцию. Выпадает случ. величина от 0 до 100. если она < 20 => то это 10, если < 45 (20+25) то 15 и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно заполнить массив числами так, чтобы количество вхождений каждого соответствовало вероятности его появления в выдаче.

```
$a = array(10,15,40,12);
$ver = array(20,25,5,50);
unset($b);
foreach($a as $key => $val) {
  for($i = 0; $i < $ver[$key]; $i++) {
    $b[] = $val;
  } 
}
shuffle($b);
printf($b[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Расписываем коэффициенты *(чтобы были всегда проценты - делим каждое на сумму всех и думаем, что делать с точностью)*:

```
$chancesMap = [
    10 => 20,
    15 => 25,
    40 => 5, 
    12 => 50,
];
```

Пишем функцию:

```
/**
 * @param array $chancesMap Value => Chance
 * @return mixed
 * @throws Exception
 */
function getRandomValue($chancesMap) {
    $chancesSum = array_sum($chancesMap);

    $randomValue = rand(1, $chancesSum);

    foreach ($chancesMap as $value => $chance) {
        $randomValue -= $chance;

        if ($randomValue <= 0) {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception('Не может быть');
}
```

Проверяем:

```
$testIterations = 10000;
$results = array_flip(array_keys($chancesMap));

// запустим несколько раз..
for ($i = 0; $i < $testIterations; $i++) {
    $value = getRandomValue($chancesMap);   
    $results[$value]++;
}

// проценты..
array_walk($results, function(&$count, $value) use ($testIterations) {
    $count = round($count / $testIterations * 100, 2);
});

var_dump($results);
```

Получается:

```
array(4) {
  [10]=> float(19.7)
  [15]=> float(25.13)
  [40]=> float(5.39)
  [12]=> float(49.84)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насчет библиотеки, едва ли она есть. Делается это просто

```
$a = array (10, 15, 40, 12);
$prob = array (20, 45 /*20+25*/, 50 /*45+5*/, 100/*50+50*/)
$r = rand(0, 100) /* включительно, желательно равномерное распределение */
for ($i = 0; $i<4; $i++) {
    if ($r <= $prob[$i]) return $a[$i];
}
```

сорри за псевдокод, php знаю очень слабо.